# How to use a variable in a quotation in C

Tags: c

I really have no idea how to Google search on this specific topic, so I hope one of you guys can help me out here.

Basically I've got this code:

```
fp = fopen("ELSO.html", "w");
```

I also got a variable with a name:

```
char name[25] = {"JohnShepard"};
```

What I want is to call fopen so that the name would be JohnShepard.html (i.e the content of the variable). Is such thing even possible?

Comment: You can use the string concatenation function, `strcat`. Something like: `fp = fopen(strcat(name, ".html"), "w");`

Comment: There's no need for braces around the string.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to `strcat`, you can use [`snprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html):

```
char buffer[100];
char name[25] = "JohnShepard";

int i = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%s.html", name);
// "i" should now contain the length of string in "buffer"

FILE *fp = fopen(buffer, "w");
// ... etc ...
```

This method is safer than `strcat` because it requires you to provide the size of the output buffer. If there isn't enough room, then you won't end up overrunning the buffer (which is dangerous). Also, it doesn't modify the original string, but whether that is important or not is up to you.

Comment: Although it will open the wrong file if the buffer is too small, which could be a security issue